# Цикл в столбце datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Хочу сделать заполнение данных в столбце циклом, чтобы через каждые 2, 4, 8 строчки менялись данные (0,1) (см.рис)

Знаю как через 1, но не могу уловить логику как сделать дальше.(см.ниже код).

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
{
    if ((i % 2) == 0)
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "0";
    else
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "1";
}
```

[image: столбец с значением (0,1)]

Comment: Ну если вам таким же способом нужно, то можно так попробовать: `int v = i / n; (где n - нужный Вам интервал); if(v % 2 == 0) то 0 else 1

Comment: @Алексей Cаровский,дай вам Бог здоровья ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно Вас понял то так:

```
int counter=2;
{
    counter+=2;
    if(counter==6) counter+=2;
    if ((i % counter) == 0)
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "0";
    else
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "1";
    if(counter==8) counter=2;
}
```

Ну естественно это надо делать в цикле =)

Comment: Ваш вариант тоже работает,спасибо вам за "разнообразность" ))
Но я взял уже 1 вариант.

  `for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)  
                {
                    int v = i / 2;
                    if ((v % 2) == 0)
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "0";
                    else
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "1";
                }`